# Не правильно работает middleware Laravel

Tags: laravel

Вообщем, есть у меня роут админки

```
Route::get('home', 'AdminController@admin')->name('home');
```

Вот содержимое моего контроллера, который всё это дело обрабатывает

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('role');
}

public function admin()
{
    return view('home');
}
```

Вроде как всё просто, при переходе на home, должен сработать посредник. А вот и он сам

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{

    if(\Auth::user()->role_id != 1) {
        return redirect('')->with('success', 'У вас недостаточно прав на это действие');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Здесь я проверяю, если user_id аутентифицированного чувака не равно 1, то редиректим на главную и показываем ему банан. В итоге без разницы, на эту страницу может зайти любой пользователь, с любым user_id

Казалось бы проблема в посреднике, однако он работает, на других страницах, а тут на отрез отказывается, в чем косяк не пойму

Comment: а куда же Вы редиректите  в посреднике? redirect('')?

Comment: Если role_id не 1, то редирект на главную

Comment: Как Вы объявляете о необходимости запуска middleware на других страницах?

Comment: @ШайтанЯкубович, я подразумевал не совсем то. Попробую прояснить свою мысль. У Вас в middleware происходит пустой return redirect(''), а должно быть return redirect('/') либо redirect()->route('main_page') , где main_page - это роут на главную страницу